# How to design a horizontal card with an Image in HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, card

I have been trying to make an element like this with grid and flexbox, but I cannot get it to be responsive. Can someone give any headers as to what I will need to do?
Thanks

Here's the design
[Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIvN.png)

Comment: let us see what you have right now

Comment: @WisamShaker https://replit.com/@JeswinSunsi/Qrepl#index.html I've almost figured it out, but I can't get the icons to fit in properly with responsiveness

Comment: Can you share code so that we could help you